# In Eclipse "WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0" server missing to add

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I was trying to add a server by clicking in the *Servers* view on *"No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server..."*:

[image: here]

...and choosing the server that were available in a list. However, among the list the server I wanted to install was not to be:

[image: seen].

Earlier, I downloaded the binary version of it found at https://wso2.com/integration/previous-releases/ and installed it at `C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.4.0` as per recommendation of the product's guide.

My question is that why is there no WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0 in the "New Server" window and how do I make sure that it appears?

Answer (score 0):

This server option comes in the tooling by default and you don't need to install anything. It seems you have a tooling which was released with EI 6.3.0 product release. From here https://wso2.com/integration/tooling/ you can downlaod the latest tooling and it will have servers defined till 6.5.0 also it has an embedded server for testing purposes.

Thanks
Nirothipan

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (EI) 6.4.0 as you have the EI Tooling 6.3.0 version. You can use the **WSO2 EI 6.3.0** option from the available server list in your tooling distribution and point to a WSO2 EI 6.4.0 server home directory. It will work the same way.

However, it would be better if you can use the newest release as it has many improvements over the time.